# How to match two list with the same length

Tags: python, list, jupyter-notebook, 3d, pycharm

i have two list with the same length over 11 rows. I would like df[0] to find a match in any position in df2[0] and df[1] to find a match in any position df2[1] and etc.... Instead of me typing one by one is there a easier method?

```
   df = [[[1, 5,7,9,12,13,17],
   [2,17,18,23,32,34,45],
   [3,5,11,33,34,36,45]],
  [[6,21,22,50,56,58,72],
  [7,5,12,13,55,56,74],
  [8,23,24,32,56,58,64]]]

    df2 = [[[100,5,12,15,27,32,54],
    [120,10,17,18,19,43,55],
    [99,21,32,33,34,36,54]],
   [[41,16,32,45,66,67,76],
    [56,10,11,43,54,55,56],
    [77,12,16,18,19,21,23]]]
```

i would like my output to be like this.

```
    output = [[[[5,12,],[17]],
      [[17,18],[32,34,36]]],
      [[[55,56],[32]],[[56]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As of your reworked question, it is still not quite clear to me what exactly you want to accomplish. I assume you want element based matching. By using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32318113/find-all-common-sequences-of-two-list-in-python) we can find the matching sequences of two lists.
For the presented case, we just need to iterate over all the elements of your array.

The `matches` function will find all matching sequences. Using it in the nested for loop allows for element wise comparison. The matching sequences are the ten written to `matched_sequences` which will hold all identified matches.

```
import difflib

df = [
    [[1, 5, 7, 9, 12, 13, 17], [2, 17, 18, 23, 32, 34, 45], [3, 5, 11, 33, 34, 36, 45]],
    [[6, 21, 22, 50, 56, 58, 72], [7, 5, 12, 13, 55, 56, 74], [8, 23, 24, 32, 56, 58, 64]],
]

df2 = [
    [[100, 5, 12, 15, 27, 32, 54], [120, 10, 17, 18, 19, 43, 55], [99, 21, 32, 33, 34, 36, 54]],
    [[41, 16, 32, 45, 66, 67, 76], [56, 10, 11, 43, 54, 55, 56], [77, 12, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23]],
]


def matches(list1, list2):
    while True:
        mbs = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, list1, list2).get_matching_blocks()
        if len(mbs) == 1:
            break
        for i, j, n in mbs[::-1]:
            if n > 0:
                yield list1[i : i + n]
            del list1[i : i + n]
            del list2[j : j + n]


matched_sequences = []

for row_df, row_df2 in zip(df, df2):
    for el1, el2 in zip(row_df, row_df2):
        matched_sequences.extend(list(matches(el1, el2)))

print(matched_sequences)
```

This will produce as identified matches:

```
[[12], [5], [17, 18], [33, 34, 36], [55, 56], [23]]
```

Comment: I'm not trying to get all possible matches. Im Trying to get a match in row 1 to match row 1,2,3 in df2 and then row 2 match 1,2,3 and the row 3 to match row 1,2,3 then row 4 to match 4,5,6 and then row 5 match 4,5,6 and then row to match 4,5,6. Hopefully this make more sense

Comment: Could you please edit your original question so that it clearly sates what you are expecting as an output, and what should match what, because it is not clear for me?